# Gauge: Run background scenario (Concept.cpt) before spec

Tags: markdown, bdd, getgauge

I'm new with Gauge and I need to run something like the Background Scenario before the Scenarios (Inn this case, Specs)

I have a login in a spec like this:

```
table: resources/data/login_data.csv

## Login with valid username and password
----------------------------------------------

* Navigate to Login Profile page
* Login with profile as <Profile> and password as <Password>
* Access Mailtrap with valid username <Username> and pass <Pass>
* Successfully logged to Page
```

Now this is the concept file (Concept_Login.cpt)

```
# Login as profile <Profile> and access Mailtrap with valid username <Username>


* Navigate to Login Profile page
* Login with profile as <Profile> and password as <Password>
* Access Mailtrap with valid username <Username> and pass <Pass>
* Successfully logged to Page
```

What i want: In a different spec reuse the Login. I have an example made:

```
Second Spec File
=================


Successfull Login Scenario
--------------------------

* Login as profile <Profile> and access Mailtrap with valid username <Username>


Redirect to Contact Page
-------------------------

* Accessing to the contact section
* Click in Contacts Menu
* The contacts menu is displayed
```

But when I run this second spec file, system displays the next error:

```
[ParseError] /Users/rodrigo.g/Documents/automation_projects/Gauge/gauge_maven/specs/concepts/Concept_Login.cpt:9 Dynamic parameter <Password> could not be resolved => 'Login with profile as <Profile> and password as <Password>'
[ParseError] /Users/rodrigo.g/Documents/automation_projects/Gauge/gauge_maven/specs/concepts/Concept_Login.cpt:10 Dynamic parameter <Pass> could not be resolved => 'Access Mailtrap with valid username <Username> and pass <Pass>'
[ParseError] /Users/rodrigo.g/Documents/automation_projects/Gauge/gauge_maven/specs/normalflow.spec:12 Dynamic parameter <Profile> could not be resolved => 'Login as profile <Profile> and access Mailtrap with valid username <Username>'
[ParseError] /Users/rodrigo.g/Documents/automation_projects/Gauge/gauge_maven/specs/normalflow.spec:12 Dynamic parameter <Username> could not be resolved => 'Login as profile <Profile> and access Mailtrap with valid username <Username>'
```

By the way: concepts folder is inside of specs folder.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why is this tagged [markdown]? I don't see what Markdown has to do with this question.

Comment: The first part of the Login with valid... is written in Markdown

Comment: Yes, but aren't you asking for help in following the instrcutions? The fact that they are written in Markdown shouldn't matter for that. Unless I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Hi Waylan: I already change the second part of the question.